# Asp.net IsPostBack false not working

Tags: asp.net, refresh, controls, postback

When I do F5 the page postback feature, though the code doesn't work and continues to work.

**Example:**

`!IsPostBack` or `!Page.PostBack` or `!this.PostBack`

No one it doesn't work why?

Comment: do you get an error of some kind? it would be helpful if you could provide some more details.

Comment: Can we see the whole if-statement?

Comment: void View()
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //CodeHere
        }
    }

This code needs to work when the page is refreshed. But working

Comment: problem solved thanks.